# Representation of a group on a vector space

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory

Myself a physics student currently learning representation theory of discrete group theory.

We know the realisation of a group can be done over a vector space.I want to know , can we have two or more inequivalent representation of a group having the same dimension on  the same vector space?

Thank you

Comment: You can let any group act trivially on any vector space.

Comment: The edit does not actually change much. The above comment by Qi still answers the question.

Answer (score 1):

A linear group representation is always simply a group homomorphism $\varphi\, : \,G\longrightarrow GL(V)$. So your question reduces to: 'Does the vector space already completely determine the homomorphism?'

The answer is no. You can have a faithful representation where $\varphi$ is injective (e.g. a rotation group of a square in the Euclidean plane), or simply define - as mentioned above:  $\varphi(g)=\operatorname{id}_V$, which does not reveal anything about the group. However, this is the reason why we consider representations: study the group by its actions on the vector space. So faithful representations are much more useful. Next step is irreducibility of the representations: it is a bit like the question about the 'atoms' (= irreps) of a representation.

Comment: So you are saying we can't have more than two inequivalent representation of the group of same dimension over the the vector space right?

Comment: No, I only named two  possibilities (embedding and trivial), but there may be more, since any homomorphism will do. Of course in the end it depends on the given case, but there are usually many possibilities. The kernel of such a homomorphism is a normal subgroup of $G$, so you can construct different homomorphisms if there are different normal subgroups available. But this is again only an example. Representation theory for given groups can become quite complicated, especially for infinite topological groups which are used in physics.

Comment: Is it possible to have two inequivalent irreducible representation of a group of same dimension of same vector space?

Comment: It is possible. E.g. you can have the direct product of two different simple groups and take either factor as kernel of a group homomorphism into the same general linear group. 

I'm not quite sure whether you can have two inequivalent faithful representation, i.e. whether all possible embeddings are automatically equivalent. I suppose they are not, but I don't have an example in mind.

Comment: @p rakesh kumar dora Yes, for instance the two irreducible components of the standard representation of $\Sigma_2$ -- the permutation group of degreee $2$ -- on $K^2$, where $K$ is an arbitrary field of characteristic not equal to $2$. Both irreducible components are $1$-dimensional however not isomorphic as $K[\Sigma_2]$-modules.